# Confusion about scope and hoisting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <body>
        <ul id="people-list"></ul>
        <script src="app.js"/>
    </body>
</head>
</html>

***app.js***

var people = ["alf","kay","jay","may"];
var list = document.getElementById("people-list");
for(var i =0; i< people.length; i++){
  var person = people[i];
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  (function (){
    var person = person;
    element.innerText = person;
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert("You clicked on "+ person);
    });
  }());
  list.appendChild(element);
}
```

Why is the "person" variable created in the Global Scope not being referenced in the IIFE and therefore produces a list of undefineds but then a change in variable name from (example. var person to var person2 and subsequent change in the alert) in IIFE makes the code work correctly.

Comment: `person`isn't created in the global scope. Creating a variable without `var`definition will hoist it up to the global scope. Else it'll be created in it's corresponding scope.

Comment: And `var person = person` is pointless

Comment: But before the IIFE, there is a person variable created in the global scope to which the various indexes of people are equated to. Am I right?

Comment: Just comment `var person = person;` and test! `var person` will hoist the variable as `undefined` and this is what `variable hoisting` is all about..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to hoisting `var person = person` is exactly equivalent to

```
var person;
person = person;
```

You can't refer to the `person` variable in the outer scope. It's completely overshadowed by the local variable, so you're assigning the undefined local variable to itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the "person" variable created in the Global Scope not being referenced in the IIFE

Because you have a `person` variable in the scope of the IIFE which masks it.

If you have two variables of the same name, in different scopes, you can only access the one declared in the *nearest* scope.

---

Hoisting doesn't make a difference here because `var person` appears on the first line of the IIFE.

If it appeared on any other line in the IIFE then it would be hoisted and equivalent to having it on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `person` to refer to the outer-scope loop variable when you already use the name for the local variable, it is *shadowed*. You can either pass a parameter

```
var person = people[i];
(function (person){
    …
}(person));
```

or not use an outer-scope `person` at all:

```
(function (){
    var person = people[i];
    …
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

Declaring a variable through `var` will always use JavaScripts function scope. In order to declare variables in global scopes you'll just leave the `var` definition.

```
var person = "your person" // function scope
person = "your person" // global scope
```

Anyways, you're just declaring the same variable **twice**. Which basically means you are overwriting your previously declared definition of `person`. Doing so you just end up with an `undefined` variable as you've seen in your example.

Comment: I beg to defer in relation to your first point, I think if you create a variable with the var keyword outside of a function, it is still registered in the global scope. Type a variable into a browser console using the var keyword and and check in "window", you will find it there.